# Twilio Sendgrid - pull Individual recipient Stats with the API?

Tags: email, twilio, sendgrid, twilio-api, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm working with the Twilio Sendgrid API to send emails and get performance statistics on those emails. I found that it is very simple to get global stats for an email or even to get stats by category ... but I want to be able to get stats for an individual users. For example, did johnsmith@mail.com receive/open an email. I have tried looking through the sendgrid-api-v3 docs but couldn't find a way to achieve this. Does anyone know of a way to do this with Twilio Sendgrid's API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The best way to get updates on individual emails is to [register for event webhooks so that you can be notified when an email is delivered/opened](https://sendgrid.com/blog/track-transactional-email/).

I wrote a blog post about [how to track email statuses with SendGrid](https://www.twilio.com/blog/track-email-status-ruby-on-rails-sendgrid). The example is written in Ruby on Rails, but if that is not your platform of choice hopefully the explanation around the code should help.